# I can't clear dyes

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to clear somebody's inventory. They have one lapis and I want it to clear only one lapis at a time, and only clear lapis. Can anybody help? The command I'm currently using is:

```
/clear @p minecraft:dye 0 1
```

Comment: oh and /clear @p minecraft:dye will clear all dye and all of all dye types too btw my version is 1.10.2

Comment: also is there a way to testfor only lapis and not other dyes? thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax of `/clear` is:

```
/clear [player] [item] [data] [maxCount] [dataTag]
```

Lapis is `dye` with a data value of `4`. As you only want to clear `1` at a time, your command should be:

```
/clear @p dye 4 1
```